# YouTube API v3 invalid grant after generating new refresh token

Tags: youtube-api, unauthorized, refresh-token, youtube-data-api

We have an application which uses YouTube Data API v3 so we could be able to upload and manage videos on YouTube. For several days 
we have not been able to upload videos in YouTube, nor to list corresponding playlists from the channel or to make any other actions which require making requests to YouTube Data API.

When we try to list the playlists or to get a certain video by its Id or to upload a new video we get the following error message:

> **Error   {Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Bad Request", Uri:""}  Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenErrorResponse**

We generated new refresh token from YouTube API but when we use it, we get the same error.
Then we created a new application in YouTube developers page with new credentials and newly generated refresh token but we still are getting the same error.

We think the reason the previous refresh token has become invalid is that the last time it was used is 7 months ago (the Google's documentation indicates that a refresh token expires if "The refresh token has not been used for six months.").

Does somebody know why are not we able to use the newly generated refresh token and what should we do in order to make a successful request to the YouTube API?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure your actually using the new refresh token sounds like the one you are using is expired.    If its not that then check your clock make sure the times corect.

Comment: I have generated new refresh token following the guidance from this page: 
https://help.aolonnetwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/218079623-How-to-Create-Your-YouTube-API-Credentials. 
The refresh token never expires except some specific cases as I have pointed out above one of them. I debugged the application's requests to YouTube and I am sure that the application uses newly generated token. Unfortunately, the result is the same:  {Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Bad Request", Uri:""}

Comment: @RosenPetrov I'm running into the same issue: our client ID and client secret suddenly stopped working after months of usage with no issues. I regenerated the secret but the issue persists. I don't see any serious clock drift... Did you ever figure out what was going on here?

Comment: I have read this article: https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35 - and found my solution. In my case, our customer had not used the refresh token for more than 6 months and that was the reason to expire. When generation new refresh token you should delete or rename the expired refresh token on order to create new one.